Function return a value different from that in case (same variable). It follow question "C Multiple Func() printf - With no Reason"

This is a recursive function in C (function call itself) the Main case is:
and is returned a value of variable "i" that must be 6 but is 1 as explaned:
if(i==6){return i;} but the value returned is 1 not 6...
note that i must be == 6 to exevute
return...

Here is the code:
#include<stdio.h>

int func1(int i){
    
    if(i == 6) {  // Base Case
        printf("\nEnd1");
        return i;
    }
        
    printf("%d ", i);
    func1(i + 1);
    // printf("\nEnd1");
    return i;
    
}

int main()
{
    printf("\n%d", func1(1));
    return 0;
}


I receive 1 as i value instead of 6.
this is my Output:
1 2 3 4 5
End1
1
Expected Output:
1 2 3 4 5
End1
6
I don't know where to throw the head...
Any Solution?
The following link open a new website page click here↗ to view the code run.

(this qestion follows what asked in "C Multiple Func() printf - With no Reason".

When you do the recursive call func1(i + 1), what happens with the value it returns?

Your recursive call discards the return value. What you actually return to main is the same i that is passed from main - i.e. 1. Change the recursive call to return func1(i + 1); (and remove return i; that comes after it) to get the output you expect.

I removed last return and I got 6 as but the problem is not so simple: if I leave 2nd return I should get at least 2 for i, then why is not executed the return above "before" (that must have i = 6 and doing so not executing the return below)?

Change the statement func1(i + 1); to return func1(i + 1);

On a very different note, please make it a habit to use trailing newlines in your output. When stdout (which is where printf write its output) is connected to a terminal (which it will be almost always), then it's line buffered. That means the data in the stdout buffer will be actually written to the terminal on a newline. If you have a leading newline, you write the previous line, not the one you're currently have in your printf statement.

@some programmer dude it is icresed by 1 and printed again and this repeat untill i become 6, but may be I don't understend exactly your question...

@Some programmer dude I normaly use them, but some competitive programming sites throw wrong answer if you end a code with a newline; then if is verbose to a line is printed in after a "carriage return" is a useful solution. Also I found about this your comment a discussion on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

why is shoud be good Change the statement func1(i + 1); to return func1(i + 1); it return 2 instead of 6

I will remain chained in one of this pages

@pvt-Tron if you change the recursive call as suggested above, the final return value will be 6, not 2. See demo.

@everyone: Someone downvoted my ask, so is (-1). The reason should derive from my tailed in answers possible (partial) solution ?

The first recursive call of the function gets the value 1
printf("\n%d", func1(1));

and this value is not being changed within the function call
int func1(int i){
    
    if(i == 6) {  // Base Case
        printf("\nEnd1");
        return i;
    }
        
    printf("%d ", i);
    func1(i + 1);
    // printf("\nEnd1");
    return i;
    ^^^^^^^^^
    
}

The reurned value from this code snippet of the function
    if(i == 6) {  // Base Case
        printf("\nEnd1");
        return i;
    }

is used nowhere.
Try to change thos statement
    func1(i + 1);

to
    i = func1(i + 1);


Interesting change  func1(i + 1); to i = func1(i + 1); but atm I'm working to an differnt solution as follow...

I tried this variant and is compliant for many reasons.. then I get 5 that has no need to be adjusted in main...! (is the last value printed)
#include<stdio.h>

int func1(int i){
    //int res1;
    if(i == 6) {  // Base Case
        //res1 = i;
        printf("\nEnd1");
        return 0;
    }
        
    printf("%d ", i);
    
    int res1 = func1(i + 1);
    
    // printf("\nEnd1");
    return (res1 + 1);
    
}

int main()
{
    printf("\n%d", func1(1));
    return 0;
}

Main Changes:
        return 0;
in // Base Case
with
int res1 = func1(i + 1);   /* and */ return (res1 + 1);
in the last part of func1()
The following link open a new website page click here↗ to view the code run.
